# Seeking Guidance on Implementing SSL Certificates for Docker Containers on Local Ubuntu Server without a Custom Domain

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, https, ubuntu-22.04

Hello Community Members,

I hope this message finds you well. I am reaching out to seek assistance and clarification regarding the implementation of SSL certificates for Docker containers on my local Ubuntu server.

Here's a brief overview of my setup: I have a local server running Linux Ubuntu with Docker installed, and various containers are operating beneath it. At present, I do not have a purchased domain, but I do have a dynamic DDNS in place.

My primary goal is to secure web-accessible containers by adding SSL certificates, allowing secure HTTPS connections. Specifically, I am looking to address the persistent issue of browser warnings about insecure connections to these containers. It is worth noting that I prefer accessing the containers via the server's IP address and port, and I do not necessarily need to use the DDNS name.

The containers I'm focusing on are those with web interfaces, and the constant browser warnings about insecure connections have become quite bothersome. Simply adding container addresses to the hosts file is not a viable solution as I work with multiple machines.

I have explored solutions like Nginx Proxy Manager, which requires a custom domain, and attempted to use Let's Encrypt and Certbot in conjunction with Nginx, encountering challenges along the way.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance, recommendations, or step-by-step instructions on how to add SSL certificates to web-accessible Docker containers without relying on a custom domain. If possible, I am also interested in exploring alternative methods or tools that could facilitate this process.

Thank you in advance for your valuable insights and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

i also struggle to make SSL connection from docker container phpmyadmin to mysql, your problem similar to mine "make SSL certificate for not our own domain" (in my case the domain name is container name "mysql").

change "mysql" to your DDNS domain name.
After the certificate is generated, try import to nginx proxy manager at custom certificate section. Hope this also works for you.

[install openssl on windows](https://tecadmin.net/install-openssl-on-windows/)

###### Generate CA key pair and certificate

```
openssl genrsa -out ca-key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca-key.pem -out ca.pem -subj "/CN=mysql"
```

###### Generate client key pair and certificate request

```
openssl genrsa -out client-key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -key client-key.pem -out client-csr.pem -subj "/CN=mysql"
```

###### Sign the client certificate with the CA

```
openssl x509 -req -in client-csr.pem -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -out client-cert.pem -days 365 -CAcreateserial
```

Comment: Thank you for replaying. I have also read about openssl. That's good starting point. Question is how to associate it with containers then?

Comment: @zawier its depend on what container you running, if its a web interface then easy way is reverse proxy using nginx proxy manager. also this is a interesting topic because its also depend if you wanna access it from WAN or locally (with or without VPN) since you dont have a paid domain name.

Comment: I'd like to start from web based containers while I have more of them. I'd like to access then locally from my LAN. mayby in future I'm going to consider WAN but for now just locally is fine. Could you please describe how to handle that, please? I'm using Wireguard so sollution with VPN is also welcome ;)